# How to find "* 50" text in visual studio files?

Tags: visual-studio

I want to find a text * 50 (multiply sign space 50).

How ?

PS: I use standard "find and replace" dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type `* 50` in the find dialog. And *make sure regular expressions and wildcards are off*, because that's probably what's throwing you.